# Sending a value of a mergefield from to a website

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a mailmerg of patient specific information that is merged into an MSword document. I need to upload it to my hospital document repository. The repository puts the document in the correct place on our server by using the patient identification number. This patient identification number is one of the fields within the mail merge document. I am trying to send the patient id to the webpage without manually typing the ID into the web page. Can anyone help?  I have tried to use VBA but I can't quite get the code correct

```
    *Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'Sub IE Automated
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim sURL As String
sURL = "http://cedupload.southend.nhs.uk/"
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
With ie
.Top = 0
.Left = 0
.Width = 1000
.Height = 750
.AddressBar = False
.StatusBar = False
.ToolBar = 0
.Visible = True
.Navigate sURL
Do Until Not .Busy And .ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
.Document.all("PatientIdentifier") = ThisDocument.MailMerge.Fields.Item.Copy(Unit_No_)

Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
 End With
 Do Until Not ie.Busy
 DoEvents
 Loop
 ie.Document.all("btn btn-default").Click
 
 Set ie = Nothing
 Err.Clear
 
 End Sub*
```

Comment: Please click the edit link below the question and provide more details. Explain what went wrong and where it went wrong.

Comment: Do you want to automate IE to put some value into an input or anything else of a page? I can't reach the website you give. Could you please provide the html structure of the page you automating and tell us which element you want to operate? Beside, is there any error throw in your code?